# Remove specific areas of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem I can’t seem to wrap my head around.

I have a `div` containing content. I would like to trim this `div` into a non-rectangular shape. Such that I can see the underlying background through areas of the `div`, while the `div` itself has a background where it isn’t trimmed.

It's a bit clumsy to explain:

[image: Div with content on background with marked corners that should be cut out]
Here is a picture of a `div` containing an image, and it has a `background-color`, while sitting on a `background-image`. I would like to "cut off" the cyan corners and let the `background-image` show through there.

Like so: [image: div trimmed the way I want]

I have set up a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxGNXp) that has implemented the first picture - if that makes it easier to understand. I would like to remove all the `.cutouts` individually from the "inner" `div`.

So far I've found [`clip-path`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/) as the best candidate for doing this, but it seems to do the exact opposite of what I want.

> Specify a specific region of an element to display, rather than showing the complete area.

Maybe I'm stupid and can't see how I could use that for what I want.
Any of you got an idea of how I can achieve this?

Comment: A quick fix would be to include the background-image in `.cutouts` and set the text color transparent, if you don't mind some small irregularities at some points. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZwOVK

Comment: If all else fails you could get an image editor that could make the cyan opaque

Comment: I think the best practice would be to make a transparent image of what you want, instead of loading a full image first, then clipping stuff. We should not make the internet worship our pages for nothing.

Comment: Will your images always have a solid background color?

Comment: @Frederik.L Not quite what I was looking for :]

Comment: @MarcAudet No it won't, and I'd like to be able to move the .cutouts as well

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that comes to mind is to use a png-image with transparency. Not sure if that works for you, but otherwise you could actually use clip-path: polygon(...) if you trace the points in the path for the visible area, basically something like this:

```
+--3----------4--+
|  |          |  |
1--2          5--6
|                |
|                |
12-11         8--7
|  |          |  |
+--10---------9--+
```

Where each number would represent a point on the path. So something along the lines of `clip-path: polygon(0 5%, 5% 5%, 5% 0, 95% 0, 95% 5%, 100% 5%, 100% 95%, 95% 95%, 95% 100%, 5% 100%, 5% 95%, 0 95%)`, see example in my [forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gopqjm).

Please note that clip-path [currently doesn't work](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) in Internet Explorer.

Comment: That seems to be exactly the answer I'm looking for! :) 
So I didn't understand the clip-path well enough after all. 
Do you have a resource that explains how the polygon is defined? I can't seem to find any. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone else is wondering, I couldn't really find a good documentation on how the polygon is defined, but @Bassie link to [clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) made it possible to figure it out through trial and error :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but here are some resources:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape#Possible_shapes), [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/#toc-polygon) or [w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/#funcdef-polygon)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to simply create 5 divs - one central rectangle with another long rectangle on each side, creating the illusion of a clip-path, which I found to be quite difficult to work with.

Alternatively, you could try a clip-path generator, like [clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/). I think for this problem you would want a polygon shape.

Comment: That would be a way of doing it! 
But getting the background to align with the longer rectangles on the sides would be a problem; this was just an example though, I'd like to be able trim out more complicated shapes. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out!